# Disabling thing-at-point inside helm-ff-guess-ffap-filenames

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have `helm-find-files` bound to `C-x C-f` since it provides a much more convenient way to open files. Unfortunately for me, if point is currently inside something that looks like a filename then that alters `helm-find-files`'s behaviour, often changing its current directory. (See https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/1178 )

Is there a straightforward way for me to nobble `thing-at-point` inside `helm-find-files-initial-input` so that it never believes point is inside a filename? I thought that `defadvice` would help but I'm having trouble working out how.

Or perhaps there's a better way to make `helm-find-files` behave consistently no matter where point is without modifying its implementation directly?

Comment: I don't really understand this question. The point of `helm-ff-guess-ffap-filenames` is that if you set it to `nil` then helm won't try to guess a filename based on what's around the current point. Have you tried just setting it to `nil`?

Comment: Are you sure? The default value for `helm-ff-guess-ffap-filenames` appears to be nil, and it's apparently nil for me anyway. However, I think I may know how I have caused confusion. The function I'm trying to nobble `thing-at-point` in is actually named `helm-find-files-initial-input`; I'll correct the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `helm-find-file-ignore-thing-at-point` to `t`.

**Documentation:**

```
Use only ‘default-directory’ as default input in ‘helm-find-files’.
I.e text under cursor in ‘current-buffer’ is ignored.
Note that when non-nil you will be unable to complete filename at point
in ‘current-buffer’.
```

Comment: That variable appears to have been added about nine months after my question was asked in 1ae230e5fa8dbbdbb4ed49b484f53b5d8c427c0b . That's great news, but I've jumped ship to ivy now. :) Thanks for replying.